# Verify whether a validation message is appearing using Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I want to check whether a validation message is appearing using Selenium IDE. If the validation message is appearing then the textbox should be filled with a default value automatically. If the validation message is not appearing, then the remaining steps should be executed.

I have tried this:

```
verifyTextPresent | Target | validation message
gotoif |  | jump
--Other steps--
label | jump |
```

What should i give on target field of gotoif for my condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a validation message element in your target.

Comment: I added the validation message element in the target. Now, it is showing an error message like,                                [error] Unexpected Exception: SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag b. fileName -> chrome://flowcontrol/content/extensions/goto-sel-ide.js?1389327057686, lineNumber -> 129, columnNumber -> 12